# lein test throws NPE for function using "resolve"; works in REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

`lein test` throws a NullPointerException when testing a function that uses `(resolve (symbol "a-fn"))` to return function `a-fn`. The test runs fine from the REPL.

I have not been able to find a way to resolve `a-fn` in the testing suite for leiningen, if that is indeed the issue.

I created a Leiningen project called my-resolve by `lein new my-resolve` and added two functions and tests for them:

src/my_resolve/core.clj:

```
(ns my-resolve.core)

(defn a-fn [] "From a-fn")

(defn my-resolve [] (resolve (symbol "a-fn")))
```

test/my_resolve/core_test.clj:

```
(ns my-resolve.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [my-resolve.core :refer :all]))

;; Passes
(deftest a-fn-test
  (testing "a-fn"
    (is (= (a-fn)
           "From a-fn"))))

;; my-resolve-test behaves correctly in the REPL (the test passes,
;; returns nil) but throws a NullPointerException when called from
;; lein test.
(deftest my-resolve-test
  (testing "my-resolve"
    (is (= ((my-resolve))
           "From a-fn"))))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` delegates to `ns-resolve` using the dynamically bound `*ns*`, which at the point of the call in `my-resolve.core/my-resolve` will be different depending on what namespace it is being called from:

```
user=> (doc resolve)
-------------------------
clojure.core/resolve
([sym] [env sym])
  same as (ns-resolve *ns* symbol) or (ns-resolve *ns* &env symbol)
```

I assume that in the REPL you are calling `my-resolve` when in the `my-resolve.core` ns. When `lein test` executes the test in `my-resolve.core-test`, `*ns*` is dynamically bound to `(the-ns 'user)` and that ns (most likely) does not contain a binding to `my-resolve`.

Comment: In the example, `a-fn` and `my-resolve` appear to be parallel in definition and testing but are not. `lein test` executes `a-fn-test` correctly. How did you get `lein test` to execute `my-resolve-test` correctly?

Comment: To get `lein test` to execute correctly you will need to change the code in the `my-resolve` function to something like `(ns-resolve 'my-resolve.core 'a-fn)`.

Comment: Excellent. What threw me was needing to specify the namespace in which my-resolve was already defined.